# MySQL Multiple JOINS with at least one LIKE containing a value

Tags: mysql

we have the table pages were we want to join 4 different tables on pages.uid = tableX.pid and we only want those results if for example tableX.ext_url matches a LIKE.  i've written following query but it still returns values were all 'LIKE' values are null - and the result of that are to much results

```
SELECT pages.uid, pages.title, tt_news.ext_url, tt_content.bodytext, tx_mask_facts.tx_mask_link, tx_mask_links.tx_mask_link FROM pages 
LEFT JOIN tt_news ON pages.uid = tt_news.pid AND tt_news.ext_url LIKE '%//media.%' AND tt_news.deleted <> 1 AND tt_news.hidden <> 1
LEFT JOIN tt_content ON pages.uid = tt_content.pid AND tt_content.bodytext LIKE '%//media.%' AND tt_content.deleted <> 1 AND tt_content.hidden <> 1
LEFT JOIN tx_mask_facts ON pages.uid = tx_mask_facts.pid AND tx_mask_facts.tx_mask_link LIKE '%//media.%' AND tx_mask_facts.deleted <> 1 AND tx_mask_facts.hidden <> 1
LEFT JOIN tx_mask_links ON pages.uid = tx_mask_links.pid AND tx_mask_links.tx_mask_link LIKE '%//media.%' AND tx_mask_links.deleted <> 1 AND tx_mask_links.hidden <> 1
WHERE
pages.deleted <> 1 AND pages.hidden <> 1
GROUP BY pages.uid;
```

how can i achive that?

another try:

```
SELECT pages.uid, pages.title FROM pages 
LEFT JOIN tt_news ON pages.uid = tt_news.pid
LEFT JOIN tt_content ON pages.uid = tt_content.pid
LEFT JOIN tx_mask_facts ON pages.uid = tx_mask_facts.pid
LEFT JOIN tx_mask_links ON pages.uid = tx_mask_links.pid
WHERE
pages.deleted <> 1 AND pages.hidden <> 1
AND
tt_news.deleted <> 1 AND tt_news.hidden <> 1
AND 
tt_content.deleted <> 1 AND tt_content.hidden <> 1 
AND 
tx_mask_facts.deleted <> 1 AND tx_mask_facts.hidden <> 1
AND 
tx_mask_links.deleted <> 1 AND tx_mask_links.hidden <> 1
AND 
tt_news.ext_url LIKE '%media.%'
AND 
tt_content.bodytext LIKE '%media.%'
AND 
tx_mask_facts.tx_mask_link LIKE '%media.%'
AND
tx_mask_links.tx_mask_link LIKE '%media.%'
GROUP BY 
pages.uid;
```

and another try:

```
SELECT pages.uid, pages.title, tt_news.ext_url, tt_content.bodytext, tx_mask_facts.tx_mask_link, tx_mask_links.tx_mask_link FROM pages 
LEFT JOIN tt_news ON pages.uid = tt_news.pid AND tt_news.ext_url LIKE '%//media.%' AND tt_news.deleted <> 1 AND tt_news.hidden <> 1
LEFT JOIN tt_content ON pages.uid = tt_content.pid AND tt_content.bodytext LIKE '%//media.%' AND tt_content.deleted <> 1 AND tt_content.hidden <> 1
LEFT JOIN tx_mask_facts ON pages.uid = tx_mask_facts.pid AND tx_mask_facts.tx_mask_link LIKE '%//media.%' AND tx_mask_facts.deleted <> 1 AND tx_mask_facts.hidden <> 1
LEFT JOIN tx_mask_links ON pages.uid = tx_mask_links.pid AND tx_mask_links.tx_mask_link LIKE '%//media.%' AND tx_mask_links.deleted <> 1 AND tx_mask_links.hidden <> 1
WHERE
pages.deleted <> 1 AND pages.hidden <> 1
AND
tt_news.ext_url IS NOT NULL
AND
tt_content.bodytext IS NOT NULL
AND
tx_mask_facts.tx_mask_link IS NOT NULL
AND
tx_mask_links.tx_mask_link IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY pages.uid;
```

still no success

as suggested:

```
SELECT pages.uid, pages.title, tt_news.ext_url, tt_content.bodytext, tx_mask_facts.tx_mask_link, tx_mask_links.tx_mask_link FROM pages 
LEFT JOIN tt_news ON pages.uid = tt_news.pid AND tt_news.ext_url LIKE '%//media.%' AND tt_news.deleted <> 1 AND tt_news.hidden <> 1 AND tt_news.pid IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN tt_content ON pages.uid = tt_content.pid AND tt_content.bodytext LIKE '%//media.%' AND tt_content.deleted <> 1 AND tt_content.hidden <> 1 AND tt_content.pid IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN tx_mask_facts ON pages.uid = tx_mask_facts.pid AND tx_mask_facts.tx_mask_link LIKE '%//media.%' AND tx_mask_facts.deleted <> 1 AND tx_mask_facts.hidden <> 1 AND tx_mask_facts.pid IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN tx_mask_links ON pages.uid = tx_mask_links.pid AND tx_mask_links.tx_mask_link LIKE '%//media.%' AND tx_mask_links.deleted <> 1 AND tx_mask_links.hidden <> 1 AND tx_mask_links.pid IS NOT NULL
WHERE
pages.deleted <> 1 AND pages.hidden <> 1
GROUP BY pages.uid;
```

but still same results

**final query - working example:**

```
SELECT pages.uid, pages.title, tt_news.ext_url, tt_content.bodytext, tx_mask_facts.tx_mask_link, tx_mask_links.tx_mask_link FROM pages 
LEFT JOIN tt_news ON pages.uid = tt_news.pid AND tt_news.ext_url LIKE '%//media.%' AND tt_news.deleted = 0 AND tt_news.hidden = 0
LEFT JOIN tt_content ON pages.uid = tt_content.pid AND tt_content.bodytext LIKE '%//media.%' AND tt_content.deleted = 0 AND tt_content.hidden = 0
LEFT JOIN tx_mask_facts ON pages.uid = tx_mask_facts.pid AND tx_mask_facts.tx_mask_link LIKE '%//media.%' AND tx_mask_facts.deleted = 0 AND tx_mask_facts.hidden = 0
LEFT JOIN tx_mask_links ON pages.uid = tx_mask_links.pid AND tx_mask_links.tx_mask_link LIKE '%//media.%' AND tx_mask_links.deleted = 0 AND tx_mask_links.hidden = 0
WHERE
pages.deleted <> 1 AND pages.hidden <> 1 AND (tt_news.ext_url IS NOT NULL OR tt_content.bodytext IS NOT NULL OR tx_mask_facts.tx_mask_link IS NOT NULL OR tx_mask_links.tx_mask_link)
GROUP BY pages.uid;
```

so the problem was the missing AND after the where clause with the nested OR's on the LIKE values)

sorry for my bad english tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will work:**

Write another condition checking `AND tableX.pid IS NOT NULL`

Comment: did not work as expected - i added the query to the question

Comment: i tried it as additional condition for the join after the ON and as additional condition after the WHERE

Comment: Try using `INNER JOIN`. Hope it helps

Comment: i edited your answer with a wildcard and the working example